# Unable to see last login or the login history for some users

Tags: date, user, user-management, login-history

when i go to Setup----> users-----> i could see the list of users.

I could not see the last login date for some users and also the login history for them. Can i know the reason for it.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)!

That usually means that the user has never logged in.

Comment: Heh! Why, yes, of course. Upvoted.